# How to use set-user-ID bit on directories?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I want all files in directory `/home/alex/foo` to be owned by `alex`, no matter who creates them. I'm trying this technique, but it doesn't work (on CentOS 5, under `root`):

```
$ cd /home/alex
$ mkdir foo
$ chmod u+s foo
$ chown alex foo
$ ls -al . | grep "foo"
drwsr-xr-x  2 alex root      4096 Nov 14 14:18 foo
$ echo "test" > foo/test.txt
$ ls -al foo
total 12
drwsr-xr-x  2 alex root   4096 Nov 14 14:19 .
drwxr-x--- 13 alex root   4096 Nov 14 14:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      6 Nov 14 14:19 test.txt
```

As you see, the file is owned by `root`, but should be owned by `alex`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know you can do `ls -ld foo` instead of using `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setuid on directories does not work like setgid on directories in *nix.

Comment: to expound, an average user (not root) doesn't have the permission to set a file as another's userid. Technically this is CAP_FOWNER (and maybe CAP_FCHOWN) and as far as I'm aware, root is the only user with a CAP_FOWNER capability in Linux.

Comment: You mean that my use case is not going to work, by design?

Comment: That is correct.